# Quicker way in Find-file with helm?

Tags: helm

In emacs with helm, I can `C-x C-f` find file. After type part of the folder name, helm find the right folder. At this point, I can

1. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter Dired mode. and `C-s` to search a second level folder...
2. or hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete the folder name, and continue type part of the second foler name.

Is there a way to find-file quicker like in the sublime text editor? (fuzzy search both the file names and folder names).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Helm Projectile to jump around files in projects easily. There are [some demos at the top of my guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html). You can even treat any directory as a project and jump to anywhere by making an empty `.projectile` file in that directory, if your project is not directly supported by Projectile. Projectile not only provides jumping to files/directories from anywhere at anytime, but you can also jump to any file at cursor, in any file without merely the filename.

For jumping to find, use `helm-projectile-find-file`, bound to <kbd>C-c p f</kbd> by default.

For jumping to directory, use `helm-projectile-dir`, bound to <kbd>C-c p d</kbd> by default.

To switch between recognized projects, use `helm-projectile-projects`, bound to C-c p p.

Projectile can possibly be used in a directory with a large number of files (i.e. your home directory with something like 80k-100k files) by enable caching:

```
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)
```

Depend on your hard drive, the first time starting `helm-projectile-find-file` may take a while to retrieve the file list and block Emacs. But this only happens **once**. Subsequent access you get the file list instantly until you invalidate the cache.

Note that you can fuzzy match without entering a space between search terms. The difference is that, if you add a space, Helm reverts to its old matching behavior: exact match with regex. Without a space, Helm uses the fuzzy matching similar to the one you see in Sublime Text.

Comment: Wow! This is really life-changing! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nick I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. I think add `cashing` to your answer would make more people appreciate `projectile`. (I added a `.projectile` file to my home directory, which makes everything slow down. I read your guide and add `(setq projectile-enable-caching t)` to my setup, everything is magically fast! I think others would tend to do it as well.)